# Copy to first empty cell of a specific row

Tags: variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to create a script that will copy the value of my source cell (‘Save’!B2) to a new target cell. I want the target cell to always be the first blank cell of the active row. (The active row is defined by ‘Save’!B1)

Sadly, my current formula is copying the cell information to the last column of the array +1.

This is my formula so far:

```
function saveData() { 
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
const saveSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Save'); 
const saveRow = saveSheet.getRange('B1').getValue(); 
const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data'); 
const names = dataSheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues().flat(); 
const targetIndex = names.indexOf(saveRow); 

if (targetIndex === -1) { ss.toast(Name '${saveRow}' cannot be found.); return; } 

  dataSheet.getRange(targetIndex + 1, dataSheet.getLastColumn() + 1)
 .setValue(saveSheet.getRange('B2').getValue()); ss.toast(Data saved.); }
```

Sample worksheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wutGF_PIXNnISzCkCvXm5OkzP1cvVeTxfZ3_eVILkgY/edit

So far I've tried using `getLastColumn` and `getNextDataCell.Direction.NEXT`

Edit to add in some screenshots to elaborate what I am looking for.

- [Save sheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7lyl.png)
- [Data sheet screenshot explaining what I hope to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2icV5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get all the values of the row selected, get the length of it and then add the new values.
Your script modified:

```
function saveData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const saveSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Save');
  const save = saveSheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  const names = dataSheet.getRange('a:a').getValues().flat();
  const targetIndex = names.indexOf(save);

  if (targetIndex === -1) {
    ss.toast(`Name '${save}' cannot be found.`);
    return;
  }
  //get values of selected row and its length
  const selectedRow = dataSheet.getRange(targetIndex + 1, 1, 1, dataSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
  const lastColumnSelectedRow = selectedRow.filter(String).length
  
  dataSheet.getRange(targetIndex + 1, lastColumnSelectedRow+1).setValue(saveSheet.getRange('B2').getValue());
  ss.toast(`Data saved.`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function saveData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Save');
  const saveRow = sh.getRange('B1').getValue();
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  const names = dataSheet.getRange('A1:A' + sh.gerLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const targetIndex = names.indexOf(saveRow);
  if (targetIndex === -1) {
    ss.toast(`Name ${saveRow} cannot be found.`);
    return;
  }
  dataSheet.getRange(targetIndex + 1, dataSheet.getLastColumn() + 1)
    .setValue(sh.getRange('B2').getValue());
  ss.toast('Data saved.');
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this, but that continues to copy the data to the end column +1 of the array rather than the last column of the row +1.

Comment: Yes I  could use some images of sheets show what you want to happen before and after.  I   do my best to avoid thinking whenever possible.

Comment: Hi Cooper, I have added screenshots to hopefully better explain what I’m after. thanks!